# aws elastic beanstalk composer suddenly fails

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been able to deploy my laravel application without any issues until this morning. I've changed nothing with composer, and have the following settings in my .ebextensions folder

```
commands:
    001_update_composer:
        command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
      option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
      value: /root
```

I get the following errors in the instance log when trying to deploy

```
[DEBUG] Action for aws-eb-command-handler output: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","truncated":"true","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"[CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_composer_install.sh] command failed with error code 1: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh\n++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir\n+ EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck\n+ cd /var/app/ondeck\n+ '[' -f composer.json ']'\n+ export COMPOSER_HOME=/root\n+ COMPOSER_HOME=/root\n+ '[' -d vendor ']'\n++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config optionsettings -n aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini -o composer_options\n+ PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=--no-dev\n+ echo 'Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.'\nFound composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.\n+ composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-dev\n\n                                                                                            \n  [RuntimeException]                                 ","returncode":1,"events":[]}]}
```

and

```
2016-01-19 03:40:10,193 [ERROR] Command 001_update_composer (export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update) failed
2016-01-19 03:40:10,194 [DEBUG] Command 001_update_composer output: 

  [RuntimeException]                                                                        
  The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly  


self-update [-r|--rollback] [--clean-backups] [--no-progress] [--] [<version>]


2016-01-19 03:40:10,194 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_0_uo: Command 001_update_composer failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 511, in run_config
CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 247, in build
changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 113, in apply
raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command 001_update_composer failed
2016-01-19 03:40:10,223 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 001_update_composer failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 122, in <module>
worklog.build(detail.metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 117, in build
Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 502, in build
self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 511, in run_config
CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 247, in build
changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 113, in apply
raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command 001_update_composer failed
```

If I remove the self-update call, I get this error

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-4a696c53] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_composer_install.sh] command failed with error code 1: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh
++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
+ EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
+ cd /var/app/ondeck
+ '[' -f composer.json ']'
+ export COMPOSER_HOME=/root
+ COMPOSER_HOME=/root
+ '[' -d vendor ']'
++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config optionsettings -n aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini -o composer_options
+ PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=--no-dev
+ echo 'Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.'
Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.
+ composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-dev


  [RuntimeException]                                 .
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
```

Anything I've come across I've tried with no success. It happens on every one of my instances (even a different project) no matter of the deploy version. I can update composer locally, and on the server in question if I ssh into it and do it manually. I could deploy just fine until this morning, and I haven't changed anything, so I am at a loss as to what it could be.
I am running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.9 running PHP 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with Composer itself.
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4789
By adding `1.0.0-alpha11` after `self-update` and adding 

`- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: HOME
    value: /root`

in `option_settings` resolved the issue.

Comment: `invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: mapping values are not allowed here in "<reader>", line 7, column 20: option_name: HOME ^ , JSON exception: Unexpected character (c) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.` - Any idea?

Comment: Whitespace is important, so try formatting it in the same manner as fosberyi's post in the link I posted. @Justinas

Comment: It's just change in indentation. In example there is 2 white space, in my file that worked previously it's 4.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't realize it cut off the two spaces at the beginning. Everything else is exactly the same? From that error I am guessing that there may be an invisible character/spaces after the word HOME, can you try deleting any characters after that? @Justinas

Comment: I just changed `COMPOSER_HOME=/root` to `HOME=/root` and it worked. Also, maybe you can change your username to linkable? Now I can't write your username to get user-link.